# 'Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority android.support.compat.provider but i'm using androidx.core.content.Fileprovider

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-fileprovider

When I try to use

```
var apkURI = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(AndroidApp.Context, BuildConfig.ApplicationId + ".provider", file);
```

I get

```
Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority android.support.compat.provider'
```

android manifest

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

I have no idea why i'm getting this error and all sources i try to find to help yields in no information to solve it, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which node in the manifest do you put this in? I have the exact same code as you are showing, just where authorities is: `${applicationId}.fileProvider` and it works fine. This goes into the application node in your manifest.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by which node, i'm fairly new to xamarin forms development can you elaborate more please

Comment: Just like Cheesebaron sayed, you need to check the provider label is in the application label or not. Such as '<application><provider></provider></application>'. And then did you create the provider_paths.xml in the folder named xml in the Resources folder?.

Comment: In addition, where did you call the FileProvider.GetUriForFile, in the forms part or the android part? If you checked the steps and found no error, you can check the parameter.

Comment: I copied it into the ```<application><provider></provider></application> ``` as stated above and I did create a folder named xml in Android > Resources > xml > provider_paths.xml

Comment: I added it in a android part, and made an interface and called it from forms using DependencyServices

Comment: You try to use the following code. 'Context contxt = Android.App.Application.Context; var apkURI = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(context, context.PackageName + ".provider", file);'

Comment: Ok I got it to work without giving an error, but now it just opens then closes, and the apk installer prompt wont open

Comment: Did you grant the permission to the app?